# A triple voltage supply from a dual supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, synthesizer

I have build a dual power supply for an analog synth (see image below).

[image]

The input source is a 12 VAC - 1.7A adapter. It is based on the [Wall Wart power supply from Music from Outer Space](http://musicfromouterspace.com/analogsynth_new/WALLWARTSUPPLY/WALLWARTSUPPLY.php).

Now I would like to include a 5V output to drive one or more Arduinos. If I expand the power supply with a voltage regulator (LM7805) in parallel with the LM7812 regulator, would this work?

[image]

I expect that the LM7805 regulator will be less efficient as it has to bring the voltage down from 12V to 5V and will produce more heat. Therefore, I've attached all voltage regulators to heat sinks.

Might it be better to exchange the LM7805 linear voltage regulator with a switched voltage regulator? The advantage being that it is more efficient and produces less heat, while the noise might increase. I do not intend to use batteries, so efficiency is less important, and I expect that the Arduino will not take much current.

An additional question: Have I placed the fuses F1 and F2 at the correct position in the circuit?

Comment: Use a switching regulator for the 5V, not a 7805.

Comment: run it from the +12v rail instead of the unregulated voltage; less waste heat. DON'T use an SMPS for an analog music circuit, that's just sacrilege.

Comment: NB. I've changed the circuit diagrams so that the first one reflects the dual power supply I have now. @Transistor pointed this out in the first answer.

Comment: @dandavis You're just moving the heat to the +12V regulator.

Comment: @pipe; right, but presumably that's already heatsinked in the design.

Comment: @dandavis: Yes it is already heatsinked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. OP's original circuit, since removed.*

You haven't copied the power supply from Music from Outer Space correctly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjtWmO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. You can't always get what you want. This time you're lucky.*

Your arrangement in 1(b) has no ground reference between the supply and your capacitors. The voltages will be all over the place.

1(a) will work.

One fuse will suffice. Add it on the upper winding output. That way it provides protection should anything happen on the diodes or smoothing capacitors.

[image]

*Figure 3. The RS 78xx series switching regulator.*

There are a variety of three-pin 7805 replacements which have a built-in switching regulator in a package a little bigger than the 7805 1 A version. Use those for efficiency. e.g. [RS K78xx series](https://docs.rs-online.com/5574/A700000006631902.pdf).

Comment: Switching noise might annoy an audiophile, but maybe use a 6.5V DC DC and clean it up with a 5V regulator

Comment: The 5 V is for a few Arduinies, according to the OP.

Comment: Yeah, if they are using it for digital it doesn't matter with the exception of the possibility of RFI but if they have that much digital they'll have switching noise anyway.

Comment: I use the equivalent product from CUI for convenience. They have some pretty in-your-face switching noise starting at 300kHz, which is a little bit of a pain to filter to prevent it aliasing down in sensitive sampling applications. So I second Voltage Spike's suggestion. (they also radiate enough to be picked up by a scope probe with the ground lead anywhere within about 150mm of them (below the 30MHz limit))

Comment: @Transistor You are correct - I have build it on a breadboard and there one of the VAC outputs is on the reference ground. I made a drawing mistake. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Can I simply exchange the LM7805 with the R-785.0-1.0? It looks like that if I look at the data sheet, although maybe the capacitors C11 and C12 are not needed? https://no.mouser.com/datasheet/2/468/R-78-1.0-1709942.pdf

Comment: Before omitting the capacitors ask yourself, "What do I know that the manufacturers don't?" The capacitors are required to stabilise the regulator and preventing it from oscillating.

Comment: @Transistor Ah yes, of course. I still need to filter out high frequency oscillations (noise) just as with the linear regulator...

Comment: It's more than that. The switcher may be relying on one or both capacitors to actually work *and* prevent it going into oscillation.

Comment: @VoltageSpike You suggest to combine a 6.5V switching regulator to bring the voltage down with a linear 5V regulator. Is that correct? Is the noise produced by the switching regulator only a problem on the 5V rail, or would it also affect the 12V rails? I do not foresee any audio components on the 5V output, just digital.

Comment: It wouldn't affect the 12V rails, they would also be regulating.

Answer (score 2):

a) To protect against capacitor failure, delete F1 and F2, and use a single fuse ahead of D1/D2.

b) Since efficiency and size are not factors, I vote for the linear 5 V regulator.  Note that most small buck regulators require external input and output capacitors.  Also, "proper" grounding techniques are very important for conducted noise control, but they vary widely depending on the physical arrangement of the components.  KISS.

Comment: So would you say that a linear regulator is less efficient but is better noise-wise?

Comment: Yes.  Both halves of that are almost universally true.